# ASP.NET custom templates, still ASP.NET controls possible?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, asp.net-controls

Hello: we currently do not use asp.net controls (no web forms). The way we do is:

1> Read HTML file from disk
2> lookup database, parse tags and populate data

finally,
`Response.Write(page.ToString());`

here there is no possibility of using asp.net controls. What I am wondering is, if we use asp.net controls in those HTML files, is there way to process them during step 2?

Thanks and appreciate your response.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this but you might want to attach the html extension to the ASPNET ISAPI filter in your IIS and in your page, step 2, use [Server.Execute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.execute.aspx) and call out that html file. However that page will execute on its own.

If these html pages from step 1 are meant for making up parts of the page that needs to get inserted in parts of the webform (.aspx), I suggest that you make use of **master pages** instead.

If the html pages are standalone pages that need extra functionality you can simply upgrade them to webforms without codebehind if needed. Custom made macros in Visual Studio can help a great deal in this transition effort.